# How do I get the data submitted from a form with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, bind

How can I get the data that is submitted from a form with jQuery?

I know I can bind the submit function to the form

```
$('form').bind('submit',function(){});
```

and I know I can serialize the data in the form:

```
$('form').serialize();
```

But how do I get the data that was actually submitted from the form? Like if there are two submit buttons, I want to know which one was pressed. If I handle the submission with PHP I can do that, but ideally I want to get a copy of the submitted data, then return true so that the form goes on to be processed by PHP normally.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pressed submit button should be available in the serialized field list - and the other submit buttons shouldn't be in there.

However, apparently jQuery does not add submit buttons in there ([testcase](http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/vVQve/)). See http://forum.jquery.com/topic/submit-event-serialize-and-submit-buttons-get-the-button-name for a workaround.

Comment: +1 ... do name your submit buttons to take advantage of this behaviour